# Native messaging two way communication using C# app and Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I want to create a two way communication between chrome extension and C# app through chrome native messaging. But why does the **Failed to connect: Native host has exited** error when trying to execute the relevant c# app using the following code. What is the issue here?

C# code

```
 static string OpenStandardStreamIn()
{
    //// We need to read first 4 bytes for length information
    Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
    int length = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    stdin.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
    length = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

    string input = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        input += (char)stdin.ReadByte();
    }

    return input;
}

 static void OpenStandardStreamOut(string stringData)
{
    //// We need to send the 4 btyes of length information
    string msgdata = "{\"text\":\"" + stringData + "\"}";
    int DataLength = msgdata.Length;
    Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 0) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 8) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 16) & 0xFF));
    stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 24) & 0xFF));
    //Available total length : 4,294,967,295 ( FF FF FF FF )
    Console.Write(msgdata);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string message = "test message from native app.";
    OpenStandardStreamOut(message);

    while (OpenStandardStreamIn() != null || OpenStandardStreamIn() != "")
    {
        OpenStandardStreamOut("Received to Native App: " + OpenStandardStreamIn());
        OpenStandardStreamOut("Recieved: " + OpenStandardStreamIn());
    }
}
```

I created an exe file using this code.

js Code

```
var port = null;

function appendMessage(text) {
  document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += '<p>' + text + '</p>';
}

function updateUi() {
  if (port) {
    document.getElementById('connect-button').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('input-text').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('send-message-button').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('connect-button').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('input-text').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('send-message-button').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('connect-button').onclick = connect();
};

function sendNativeMessage() {
  message = { text: document.getElementById('input-text').value };
  port.postMessage(message);
  appendMessage('Sent message: <b>' + JSON.stringify(message) + '</b>');
}

function getNativeMessage(message) {
  appendMessage('Received message: <b>' + JSON.stringify(message) + '</b>');
}

function onDisconnected() {
  appendMessage('Failed to connect: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
  if (
    chrome.runtime.lastError.message ==
    'Specified native messaging host not found.'
  ) {
  }
  port = null;
  updateUi();
}

function connect() {
  var hostName = 'com.poc.myapp'; // Host directory also created in registry
  appendMessage('Connecting to native messaging host <b>' + hostName + '</b>');
  port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
  port.onMessage.addListener(getNativeMessage);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
  updateUi();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('connect-button').addEventListener('click', connect);
  document
    .getElementById('send-message-button')
    .addEventListener('click', sendNativeMessage);
  updateUi();
});
```

app.json

```
{
    "name": "com.poc.myapp",
    "description": "My Application",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\App_2\\setup.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
      "chrome-extension://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/"
    ]
  }
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Native Messaging Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Send a message to a native application.",
  "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAt17ZTIKUsP3T2f/Gs2I4Hb5yOyXojazVw931RNbFZUqlBYWBYTMFlw8wsi6QUhN3yuZnCwDWdK3vH/OxOSyfJ22i8yx+mto3ZMaBMgE4+1YIGioYFYyEjzbpjTusx7VUOKfTTl3GsVWxw29G0DHOzo8X4uEjFL9+9IaiSi4AToDPjfX2ERxKpwX5bFNtRhlKcdpZeZI0vXc24B0BTeH01F6BjUNzgj5WrRsyDg5PqYhPofAGwHMWCUaOaGUzuhroOlgYC7DDcANVxgLt2j/0RIiqfU60AXzcZRJjoQN6wV4IB65bYdx9XxiqUG2CB0nCLk2BV7z3xsTmLkdXDNZTxQIDAQAB",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon-128.png",
    "default_popup": "main.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["nativeMessaging"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to verify if .exe console app was InputRedirected. This c# code works when called from a chrome extension using Native Message.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string stdin = null;
    if (Console.IsInputRedirected)
    {

        try
        {

            System.IO.Stream inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
            int outputLength = inputStream.Read(bytes, 0, 1000);
            char[] chars = Encoding.UTF7.GetChars(bytes, 0, outputLength);
            
            string resultado = new string(chars);
            
            string inicio = resultado.Remove(4);
            string msg = resultado.ToString().Replace(inicio, "");

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            // error
        }
    }
}
```